# Запуск PHP сервера в VS Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Доброй ночи! Только начал изучать PHP, простите за тупой вопрос!
Использую VS Code, установил данную модификацию сервера для PHP.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['text'])){
    $name = $_POST['text'];
    $handle = fopen('names.txt', 'a');

    fwrite($handle, $name. "\n");
    flose($handle);
}


?>



<form method="post">

Name: <input type="text" name="text">
<input type="sumbit" name=sumbit>

</form>
```

При запуске данного кода возникает ошибка.

```
Server error: Error: spawn php ENOENT at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19) at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Зайди в `Settings - Extensions - PHP Server Configuration` и в разделе `PHP Path` укажи путь до действующего `php.exe` файла.

Перезапусти VS Code, открой нужную директорию и правой кнопкой мыши запусти сервер